# Find newest reading date and copy depth column to new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel workbook where data has been imported by the user. See image.
[image]

I want to find the most recent date and copy the depth values at the corresponding date (most recent) to a separate sheet called "Hidden" My issue is that the number of data sets imported is dependent on how many data sets the user imports therefore it is dynamic. As well the cell where the Reading Date is located is dynamic depending on how many values there are for depth (wont always be 17.5)

Here is some code I have been working with

```
Sub Copy_Depth1()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

j = 1
i = 1

Do Until j = Sheets("Hidden").Range("B2").Value 'I count how many times data has been imported to this sheet in this cell in this specific case j is 3

With Sheets("Data Importation Sheet")
Set Cell2 = .Columns(i).Find(What:="Reading Date:", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlDown, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
Set Cell3 = Cell2.Offset(1, 0)
Debug.Print Cell3.FormulaR1C1
End With

i = i + 7
j = j + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Any tips/help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: By "Recent Date" do you mean the closest date to the day you run this macro? Also, you're currently just looking for the text "Reading Date:", instead of the actual closest date -- is that where you're having trouble?  In the data you posted, I assume you want to copy the data from the November 2016 group?

Comment: Yes I want to find the date closest to todays date. I was trying to find reading date because I know that is constant and then offset to find the actual date. In this case I would want to copy the depth values for the November 2016 group.

Comment: Why are you iterating through the columns with `i`? This should just return a single column, right? Not multiple?

Comment: Because I know that the most recent date will fall either in column 1, 8, or 15 (in this case). I am going through each of these columns to find the most recent date... If there is a better way to get the most recent date let me know. I am not very experienced with vba so there is probably a more efficient way to complete this task

Comment: @BruceWayne Do I need to use an array?

Comment: You could. I'm working on an answer though, without needing an Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Copy_depth_Updated()
Dim dataWS As Worksheet, hiddenWS As Worksheet
Dim tempDate As String, mostRecentDate As String
Dim datesRng As Range, recentCol As Range, headerRng As Range, dateRow As Range, cel As Range

Set dataWS = Worksheets("Data Information Sheet")
Set hiddenWS = Worksheets("Hidden")

Set headerRng = dataWS.Range(dataWS.Cells(1, 1), dataWS.Cells(1, dataWS.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
'headerRng.Select

For Each cel In headerRng
    If cel.Value = "Depth" Then
        Set dateRow = cel.EntireColumn.Find(what:="Reading Date:", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
        Set datesRng = dataWS.Cells(dateRow.Row + 1, dateRow.Column)
        'datesRng.Select

        ' Find the most recent date
        tempDate = Left(datesRng, 10)
        If tempDate > mostRecentDate Then
            mostRecentDate = tempDate
            Set recentCol = datesRng
        End If
    End If
Next cel

Dim copyRng As Range
With dataWS
    Set copyRng = .Range(.Cells(2, recentCol.Column), .Cells(.Cells(2, recentCol.Column).End(xlDown).Row, recentCol.Column))
End With

hiddenWS.Range(hiddenWS.Cells(2, 1), hiddenWS.Cells(copyRng.Rows(copyRng.Rows.Count).Row, 1)).Value = copyRng.Value

End Sub
```

It's a little verbose, but should work.  It will look for the columns with "Depth", and then look at that column's date. This should allow you to add/remove columns in the groups so it's a little more dynamic.

Let me know if this needs tweaking or anything.

Comment: I will work with this code for a bit but the text "Reading Date" won't always be located in Row 38. It depends on the depth reading. Depth could be 20, 30, 10, etc.

Comment: My dataset wont always be from row 2 - 35 either. It could be larger or smaller

Comment: As well the Reading Date could vary in different rows on the worksheet, for one data set it could be row 20 and for the next data set it could be row 21

Comment: @hdk857 - Are those all the variables? ...can I assume that the data would start on row 2 though?

Comment: Yes you can assume the data will always start in row 2. But the amount of depth values can vary, therefore causing the reading date to be in a different cell. I will upload another picture for reference

Comment: I have updated the image within my question for reference

Comment: @hdk857 - Thanks! One final thing - can I assume that the Depths WILL start in Column A, and be separated by 6 columns until the next one? Or is it possible that you may add a new column, or one group has an additional column other groups don't?

Comment: Depth will always start in column A and there will always be separated by 6 columns!

Comment: @hdk857 - Okay, I edited the code. It should work for you now.  Again, it's going to paste in "Hidden" column A, without a header.

Comment: is there a way for me to check if all imported data sets contain the exact same depth values as specified in the most up-to-date data set?